Does rotating steel wheel close to permanent magnet produce electromagnetic field?
Permanent magnet can be used as brake for steel wheels/flywheels.
Does rotating steel wheel close to permanent magnet produce electromagnetic field and is this files static or change in time(has frequency)?

When a metal wheel is rotated in a static magnetic field, eddy currents are induced in the metal wheel. This current will create a reaction magnetic field to the original magnetic field. Also, because the metal wheel has resistance, there will be an electric field generated within the wheel as well.
If the metal wheel is rotating at a constant speed, and the permanent magnet is not otherwise moving, the system will arrive at a steady state, and the fields will be(come) static.

If metal wheel rotate at not constant speed(acceleration and deceleration) than EM field is not static, wheel emit EM waves in  the space?

yes, if wheel speed varies, the eddy current will vary as well, and so will the electric field and reaction magnetic field.

So we can measure  this with  extremely low frequency meter in case wheel is spinning at low rpm?
